# How to add button into 1 column

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have code like this

```
 <TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
      datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", 
       <Button variant="success">Edit</Button>]}
/>
```

If I have two buttons on `"Action"` column how can I add more button, anyone can help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the way you do it, then this solution should be enough:

```
<TableItem
    columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
    datas={[
        "1", 
        "https://place-hold.it/100x150", 
        "MIlk tea", 
        "Milk tea", "100000",
        <>
            <Button variant="success">Edit</Button>
            <Button>Second Button</Button>
        </>
    ]}
/>
```

Comment: Thank so much for you useful comment, I have one more question, If I have more data, how can I add in that case, can you help me for this, I am sorry if I have bothered you, cause I just learn about ReactJs so I can not understand more, so I really need help

Comment: You have to be a bit more specyfic. What does more data mean? more positions, or diferent shape?

Comment: Okay, my question like this: `<TableItem
    datas={[
        "1", 
        "https://place-hold.it/100x150", 
        "MIlk tea", 
        "Milk tea", "100000",
        <>
            <Button variant="success">Edit</Button>
            <Button>Second Button</Button>
        </>
    ]}
/>` That is just one data for column, if I have more data in that column, how can I add it

Comment: So your `datas` would be a single "ROW" of the table, and you want to have multiple rows? If that's the case you would probably need to change how `<TableItem>` component works and instead of prop `datas` which is an array of cells, you would have to implement a prop `rows` that would be an array of `datas`. I won't be able to write definitive solution without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

pass actions as array of components

```
<TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
          datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", 
           [
<Button variant="success">Edit</Button>,
<Button variant="success">Edit</Button>,
<Button variant="success">Edit</Button>
    ]
]}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another button like this.

```
 <TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
  datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", 
  <React.Fragment>
  <Button variant="success">Edit</Button>
    <Button variant="success">New Button</Button>
 </React.Fragment>
]}
/>
```